# How to move an object in x y (diagnoal) direction in Silverlight C#

Tags: silverlight-4.0

i want to move an canvas in diagonal direction
when i tried to TranslateTransform in xaml it works but from code behind it is not working

```
<Canvas.RenderTransform>
   <TranslateTransform X="1" Y ="1"/>
</Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

code:-

```
public void AnimateTo(Canvas c)
{
        // update the value
        TranslateTransform translate = c.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
        translate.Y = --x;
        translate.X = --y;
}
```

Can some one help me

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the RenderTransform this way in code.  Set a name to your TranslateTransform tag like this :

```
<Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform x:Name="myCanvasTranslate" X="1" Y ="1"/>
</Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

then in code, use :

myCanvasTranslate.X++;

myCanvasTranslate.Y++;